# Building React front end for Solidity project

Tags: reactjs, solidity, truffle

I have a set of onlyOwner methods that I need to run right when I deploy the contract (creating games within a contract). What's the best way to auto-initiate state for testing purposes? Using Truffle, React, Ganache

Comment: Checkout my answer below. If that's what you are looking for, please accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a migration like this and the filename is `2_cat.js`

```
var Cat = artifacts.require("./Cat.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Cat);
};
```

Running above migration will deploy the Cat contract to the network, depending on the `--network` flag you supplied i.e. `truffle migrate --network development`.

You will also get a file inside `build/contracts` folder. That file should be `Cat.json` and you will find a block like this:

```
  "networks": {
    "xxx": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x...",
      "transactionHash": "0x..."
    }
  }
```

The `address` is the address of deployed Cat contract. You can take that address and launch `truffle console` in a new terminal to start interacting with it.

For example, to read something from that Cat contract, you can do something like this:

```
c = Cat.at("0x_put_address_here")
c.method_name.call()
```

To write something (alter contract state), you can do something like this:

```
c = Cat.at("0x_put_address_here")
c.method_name(arg1, arg2)
```

If you need to send that transaction from a specific address, you can do something like this:

```
c = Cat.at("0x_put_address_here")
c.method_name(arg1, arg2, {from: "0x_account_address"}) // for example, the owner
```

Be sure it's an account address. Not a contract address. And of course, that account needs to have some ETH to pay for the gas.

Okay, that's the manual process of setting contract state. To automate that, you can use `truffle exec` command and pass a JS file path.

For example, that JS file can be something like this:

```
let Cat = artifacts.require("./Cat");

module.exports = async function() {
  let c = await Cat.deployed()
  await ct.method_name(arg1, arg2, {from: "0x_account_address"})
}
```

Save that in the Truffle project root or in a directory. Then, run this command in your terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/truffle/project/root
$ truffle exec path/to/that/js/file.js --network development
```

After running the command above, your contract state should be updated. The `deployed()` function will go and find `build/contracts/Cat.json` file and take out the `address` value in the `networks`.

It's similar to `c = Cat.at("0x_put_address_here")`. But, it will smartly find the Cat address and create the contract instance for you without having you to hard code the Cat address everytime you update and deploy that contract.

The most important thing to remember here is, you need to run `truffle migrate` command first. Otherwise, the `address` value in the `networks` of `Cat.json` won't get updated and you might be updating the old contract.

Even worse, you might try to create an instance of a contract that has not been deployed because of `build/contracts/Cat.json` file is not present.

Hope this helps. I also have tweeted some more tips about `deploy()`, `new()`, `deployed()` functions and `truffle exec` in a thread [here](https://twitter.com/zulhhandyplast/status/1026181801239171072).